# Can I add comma before 'and', which is used to connect two verbs

Tags: punctuation

Is this correct?

> It is reasonable to modify the current model by stratifying on XX and XXX, and removing YYY.

Is it ok to add a comma before the second *and*, given how there is an *and* before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The comma after the second "and" shows that XX and XXX are a group and are separate from YYY.